# Rendering AMD Radeon R7 360

Tags: rendering

I am using this graphic card, but I don't know how to render via this GPU?
Is it possible? And how to do it because I don't see in options to choose my GPU.
Tnx

Answer (score 2):

The opencl support needed to use an AMD card is [not 100%](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/features.html). The [list of supported cards](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/OpenCL) hasn't been updated for a while, with some other cards also being reported [to work](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/52807/935) to varying degrees.

First check that your gpu drivers are up to date. The opencl libraries provide the list of available hardware that blender uses to [offer available GPU options](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/system.html#compute-device).

While I'm not sure if the devs are interested in [bug reports](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/) relating to opencl, they generally appreciate reports of what hardware works and what doesn't.

Answer (score -2):

1. Go to File -User preference
2. Select system (to the Right on the menu).
3. Comtute device(down to the left, on the menu) - select CUDA, then your graphic card.
4. Then use Cycles Render, go to Render-> Device-> select GPU instead of CPU.

Comment: CUDA only works with nvidia cards, the user has an AMD card.